# Bluetooth program to transfer from mobile to PC

Tags: windows-xp, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have hundreds of images on my mobile right now and want to transfer them via bluetooth to my PC running Windows XP.

I don't have a data cable or a bluetooth adapter.

How do I transfer data from mobile to PC?

Comment: Shouldn't your bluetooth adapter come with one?

Comment: @Phoshi it must detect my mobile device via bluetooth

Comment: @phoshi i dont have a bluetooth adapter

Comment: What do you want to do with it? What device are you trying to connect? What should it transfer? Please add this info to your question

Comment: @Ivo see my EDIT

Comment: Again: what phone is it? Some vendors supply their own excellent software

Comment: @Ivo sony ericsson...

Comment: What model...? Sony Ericsson has dozens of phones all with their own specific options. Plus what PC do you have? Does it have integrated bluetooth? If not, Phoshi's right: you need a bluetooth dongle/adapter

Comment: You must have bluetooth device first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an adapter your PC simply cannot do bluetooth. This is a hardware problem, not a software problem.

You can buy a USB adapter for fairly cheap, which will come with all the required software to use it, and should interface fine with any bluetooth device.

Comment: You could also hardwire the phone into the machine using the correct usb cord ( may have been sent with the phone )